# Javascript function parameters to style not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, parameters

I am working on a school project where people can change the css stylings of a page, and the javascript function parameters i am using to define what style selector to change on what element is not working.

Here is the Javascript and HTML i thats not working.

```js
function changeInput(element, styleId, styleSelector) {
 document.getElementById(styleId).style.styleSelector = element.value + "px";
}
```

```html
<!--Input width of wrapper-->
<input type="number" onchange="changeInput(this, 'demo', 'width')" value="500" min="0">

<!--The div example to change width of-->
<div id="demo" style="width:500px;height:500px;background:black;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the syntax you are using. `styleSelector` is a variable and you are calling it as `style` property. It means that JS will try to find `style.styleSelector` property which doesn't exist (when you need `style.width`).
Try to use this notation:

```
document.getElementById(styleId).style[styleSelector] = element.value + "px";
```

Take a look into `[]` brackets.